# translate DNA sequences to protein sequences within a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, biopython

I have a pandas dataframe that contains DNA sequences and gene names. I want to translate the DNA sequences into protein sequences, and store the protein sequences in a new column.

The data frame looks like:

| DNA | gene_name |
| --- | --- |
| ATGGATAAG | gene_1 |
| ATGCAGGAT | gene_2 |

After translating and storing the DNA, the dataframe would look like:

| DNA | gene_name | protein |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ATGGATAAG... | gene_1 | MDK... |
| ATGCAGGAT... | gene_2 | MQD... |

I am aware of biopython's (https://biopython.org/wiki/Seq) ability to translate DNA to protein, for example:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> coding_dna = Seq("ATGGCCATTGTAATGGGCCGCTGAAAGGGTGCCCGATAG")
>>> coding_dna.translate()
Seq('MAIVMGR*KGAR*')
```

However, I am not sure how to implement this in the context of a dataframe. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using pandas.DataFrame.apply.

Something like:

```
df['protein'] = df['DNA'].apply(lambda x: Seq(x).translate(), axis=1)
```

Comment: This works! I ended up using:

df['protein'] = df['DNA'].apply(lambda x: str(Seq(x).translate()))

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to translate each sequence in the "DNA" column, you could use a list comprehension:

```
df['protein'] = [''.join(Seq(sq).translate()) for sq in df['DNA']]
```

Output:

```
         DNA gene_name protein
0  ATGGATAAG    gene_1     MDK
1  ATGCAGGAT    gene_2     MQD
```